# Possible to generate AR(1) process without loops?

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to turn the following Python code loop into code without loops in Python?

```
steps = 10000
rho = 0.9

e = np.random.randn(steps)
y = [0]

# Possible to get rid of this loop?
for i in range(len(e)):
    y.append(rho*y[i] + e[i])
```

The code is to generate simple autoregressive (order 1) time series where given some starting value, every next value is rho time previous plus some random noise.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model

Comment: I don't understand. What is the objection to a loop exactly (so I know what is acceptable) ? What are you hoping for?

Comment: @MarkSetchell check out my code. @NeverStopLearning trying to make this type of program without loop, which can be done using `iterator`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the `numpy` tag suggests that the OP want's a fast `numpy` solution, one that uses its compiled whole-array methods.  For sequential operations like this, that can be difficult.  `numpy` is best when the operation applies to the whole array without any implied sequential action.

Comment: Changing `e` to `e = e.tolist()` speeds up the code, since it's faster to index individual list elements.

Comment: @NeverStopLearning, ...but what counts as "without a loop"? If you call a function and that function has a loop, does that count? If you use syntax that implicitly loops, does that count? Where, _exactly_, is the boundary of what is and is not a loop for purposes of this question?

Comment: `numpy` has some accumulate methods, `np.cumsum`, `np.cumprod` and various `ufunc` `accumulate`.  But applying these to your case may be impossible - unless there's an outside the box approach.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this code :

```
import numpy as np

steps = 10000
rho = 0.9
np.random.seed(0)
e = np.random.randn(steps)

z = list(np.zeros(steps))
z[:] = map(lambda x, y: rho*z[y] + x, list(e), list(range(steps)))
```

**Method-2 :**

```
m = list(np.zeros(steps))
m[:] = map(lambda x, y: m.append(rho*m[y] + x), list(e), list(range(steps)))
m = m[10000:]
print(m)
```

---

**Some quick benchmarks from ipython**

```
In [1]: timeit z[:] = map(lambda x, y: rho*z[y] + x, list(e), list(range(steps)))
1.27 ms ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: timeit m[:] = map(lambda x, y: m.append(rho*m[y] + x), list(e), list(range(steps)))
1.39 ms ± 31.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: timeit for i in range(len(e)): y.append(rho*y[i] + e[i])
8.18 ms ± 270 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Your `map` timings need to include the `z[:]` part.  `map` is just a streamlined way of doing the Python loop.  I don't think that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I don't think this replicates the OP.  Your `z` has the same values as `e`.